# No Controls at flash fallback

Tags: video.js

I want to use the free HTML5-videoplayer Video.js in a project. 
In general all of the functions are ok, but i have a problem.

For information: I am using VideoJS 4.3.

I have a problem with the flash fallback in IE7/8. The fallback is working, but when there isn't a controlbar. I think the controlbar is not just hiding, but it is not there. Only the time, the volumebar and the slider appeared. Another problem is, that the play button at the beginnen is not shown in the fallback. I've searched for this problem but the solutions don't work for me. I think it does not work, because the solutions were for older versions of video.js. What can I do so that the controlbar and the play button appears in the fallback?

Here my embedded code:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"   
controls preload="none" width="480" height="320"  poster="media/spardabank.jpg" 
data-setup="{}">
  <source src="SpardaBankHD.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  <source src="SpardaBankHD.webm" type='video/webm' />
  <source src="SpardaBankHD.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
</video>
```

In the head is this:

```
<!-- Chang URLs to wherever Video.js files will be hosted -->
<link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- video.js must be in the <head> for older IEs to work. -->
<script src="video.js"></script>

<!-- Unless using the CDN hosted version, update the URL to the Flash SWF -->
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
</script>
```

Thanks for helping,
Wuz

Comment: The play button and controls show on the player at www.videojs.com in IE8. Show some code to demonstrate what you're doing differently.

Comment: To be clear, IE7 is also technically an unsupported browser by Video.js. Can you create a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/axedog/14/edit) that demonstrates the issue so we can take a look?